# Datatables 1.10 / Columns / download_link shows but without expected data but with a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table that I have successfully created with Datatables.  I am trying to show data with a hyperlink.  When I use columnDefs, the columns performs as expected and shows a bit of data (as expected) with a hyperlink.  Here is the code:

```
// below works as expected.  It shows the ID which is the data
// in a hyperlink
"columnDefs": [{
  "targets": 0,
  "data": "download_link",
  "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
  }
}]
```

On the otherhand, I am trying to do the same thing using "columns" and it does not produce a similar result.  The below example shows "undefined" but it does produce a hyperlink to undefined.  Here is the code snipplet:

```
"ajax": "json_get_countries",
// country column does not work as expected.  It shows "undefined" and a hyperlink 
// connected to the word underdefined 
"columns": [{
    "data": "country_id",
    "searchable": false
  },
  {
    "data": "country",
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
      return '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
    }
  },
  {
    "data": "country_enabled"
  }
]
```

I have tried to remove this code:

```
"render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
  return '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
```

and it does work.  It does show the data just without the hyperlink.

I have tried to change +data+ to +country+ but that also did not work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you render a hard coded hyperlink that works? And just wondering, if what you need works when using `columnDefs`, why don't you use that technique?

Comment: seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/s8JmF/333/

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into the problem so much Dhiraj Bodicherla.  I tested a bit more and then realized data is defined twice!!!  Arrg...  It is very interesting to note that columnDefs doesn't use the name of the data but instead uses an offset from left to right (eg. "targets": 0) and maybe that is why it worked in that situation.  Arrg.  Feels like Monday morning but thank you so much for helping with this!